# How to update Couchbase system date?

Tags: java, linux, couchbase

I need to update the system date of a Couchbase cluster and/or bucket (doesn't make much of a difference for now). It is relatively easy to do in SQL DBs, but I have no clue where to look and how to do it in Couchbase. Any ideas?

Comment: Couchbase uses the OS System date but I am not sure to understand why and where you are using a date in Couchbase Server. Could you clarify your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try that one. As for clarification: what I'm looking for is a way to 'trick' the DB into 'believing' that it is e.g. 01/01/2010 13:00 (for testing purposes). Would be nice if it could be achieved without restarting anything and tampering outside the DB, but right now I could use any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CB uses the OS sysdate, the move I asked for would involve tampering with that; which is way too risky on Linux systems (and wouldn't attempt on MS, either).

I presume this wraps up the inquiry for good.